# Custom dialog collapsing when title is removed

Tags: c#, android, mobile, dialog

My app is supposed to have a button in the main activity that when pressed should show a custom dialog box that will be used as a register form for users. The problem is when I remove the title bar of my custom dialog window collapses horizontally. Any advise on how to fix this? Is the idea of using a fragment as a registration form a good one? TIA

Here is the image to Illustrate

[image: Collapsed dialog box]

Here is what it looks like with the title bar

[image]

Here is the code for the Main Activity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        mbtnfragment = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        mbtnfragment.Click += mbtnfragment_Click;



    }

    void mbtnfragment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        create_dialog dialog = new create_dialog();
        dialog.Show(transaction, "Fragment Dialog");
        Console.WriteLine("Fragment created");
    }
```

Code for the create_dialog class

```
    class create_dialog: DialogFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstancesState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: change the fragment_dialog layout's width and dont make it (wrap_content)

Comment: no prob :P, can i post it as an answer?

Comment: I guess you can, cause it did answer my question :)

Comment: yay, ill proceed to do that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the fragment_dialog layout's width from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` or a defined size

Answer (score 1):

You can set a style without title to your custom dialog

```
@Override
public void onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
}
```

Or you can set a theme in the second parameter like Theme.AppCompat.Dialog...